# Hide dynamic suggestions in search bar

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a custom theme in Wordpress, and am having trouble with the search bar.

I'm getting the search bar through the pre-defined function `get_search_form()` (default theme Twentyfourteen also uses this). Whenever I type something in the search bar, different words are displayed as suggestions. These words seem pretty random (not actual search results nor words I have searched on earlier).

[image: Wordpress search results]

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This should work:

```
$("#fields_id").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Or, on your html element:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" />
```

**HTML code path**

Goto `wp-includes/general-template.php` and find `get_search_form()`

I hope it's helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

We have checked this, Its nothing but just a search history.

Once you can clear browser search history, It will not shows the dynamic suggestion.

**For batter under standing we have capture video for the same, Would you please see video ?**

**Video URL :** http://screencast.com/t/TL2hMcwV

I hope its helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to know how to disable this. It's just not professional to have a website where all global search history is presented on our website. (To be honest I still doubt it actually is search history though, since I see many random words that I can't imagine having ever used as search queries. In my screenshot, for example, you can see the word 'after', I don't see why I'd ever look for smth like that).

Comment: We have checked that things its nothing but just browser history, Once you can clear it it will work as it should...

Comment: I get that, but I don't want other to see all of their search history either.

Comment: @poepje This should work:
$("#fields_id").attr("autocomplete", "off");
Or, on your html element:
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" />

Comment: Of these two, I'd prefer to use the html attribute directly (without jQuery), but since I get it by using `get_search_form()` I don't really know where or how. Where, if at all, could I change this?

Comment: @poepje You can change direct HTML

Comment: @poepje Search.php are available at /wp-content/themes/<theme>/views/header/global/search.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132080/discussion-between-poepje-and-mr-hk).